# How to wrap a raw string literal without inserting newlines into the raw string?

Tags: string, rust, literals

I have a raw string literal which is very long. Is it possible to split this across multiple lines without adding newline characters to the string?

```
file.write(r#"This is an example of a line which is well over 100 characters in length. Id like to know if its possible to wrap it! Now some characters to justify using a raw string \foo\bar\baz :)"#)
```

In Python and C for example, you can simply write this as multiple string literals.

```
# "some string"
(r"some "
 r"string")
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Rust?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While raw string literals don't support this, it can be achieved using the [`concat!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat!.html):

```
let a = concat!(
    r#"some very "#,
    r#"long string "#,
    r#"split over lines"#);

let b = r#"some very long string split over lines"#;
assert_eq!(a, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with [indoc](https://docs.rs/indoc/latest/indoc/).

> The `indoc!()` macro takes a multiline string literal and un-indents it at compile time so the leftmost non-space character is in the first column.

```rust
let testing = indoc! {"
    def hello():
        print('Hello, world!')

    hello()
"};
let expected = "def hello():\n    print('Hello, world!')\n\nhello()\n";
assert_eq!(testing, expected);
```

---

Ps: I really think we could use an AI that recommend good crates to Rust users.

Comment: This... does the opposite of what the question asked. They do *not* want the newlines in the resulting string.

Comment: detly's comment is true. But you are also not using raw string literals here!